# Firefox is showing "Your connection is not secure" when configuring Manual Proxy for Jmeter Performance test

Tags: firefox, proxy, configuration, jmeter, performance-testing

I am trying to configure Mozilla Firefox for Jmeter 3.2 and as I am setting up manual proxy in Firefox and same proxy number in Jmeter, my Firefox is showing error as "Your connection is not secure". Please let me know the steps if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: were you able to solve it? I am encountering the same issue today 3/30/2020 my jmeter is version 5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does. According to [JMeter's documentation on HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder):

> When connecting via HTTPS, the server presents the certificate to the browser. To authenticate the certificate, **the browser checks that the server certificate is signed by a Certificate Authority (CA) that is linked to one of its in-built root CAs**.
>
> Browsers also check that the certificate is for the correct host or domain, and that it is valid and not expired.
>
> **If any of the browser checks fail, it will prompt the user who can then decide whether to allow the connection to proceed.**

When you start JMeter's proxy server you should see a message about details of the certificate which JMeter has generated in order to be able to record HTTP(S) traffic

[image: JMeter certificate dialog]

So you need to do the following:

1. Click "Add Exception"
2. Click "Certificate Status" -> "View"
3. Validate the Certificate CN, Created Date, etc. If they match - install the certificate in order to let JMeter record secure traffic.

References:

- **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the aforementioned [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation
- [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

Also be aware that you can use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) as an alternative to HTTP(S) Test Script Recorded, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates as it provides seamless way of capturing the traffic between browser and application under test.